# Animations doesn't work in debug mode | React-Native

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native, debugging, chrome-debugging

I've got a really annoying bug for some time now.. and it's that **animations** doesn't work in the **debug mode** of a **React-Native App** properly. 
It takes about 5s until they get executed.
In **normal mode everything works fine**. 
I don't know what the reason is and there is nothing useful about this bug on the internet, yet. 
So I decided to ask you ^^

**Note**

- If you want to see how the bug looks like.. I have uploaded a short video
  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=qxpOyIHeyQg

**Used**

- react-native 0.62
- chormedebugger (also tested with [react-native-debugger](https://github.com/jhen0409/react-native-debugger))
- android (ios not tested yet)

Thank you ^^

Answer (score 0, accepted):

While turning on the debugger react-native has to do a lot more work for displaying `errors, consol.logs, redux state` and all that so when react-native got busy with all these things animation got executed in the meantime have a look at this.

https://github.com/facebook/react-native/issues/5632#issuecomment-177299394

you can try to use InteractionManager to make animations smoother.

https://reactnative.dev/docs/0.26/interactionmanager

Comment: Yeah that is right.. but is there a way to fix this... because my textinputs doesn't work properly without animations..

Comment: Does any good reason to run these animations in debug mode? have you used useNativeDriver ? or you can use InteractionactionManager to make the animation smoother.